# grunt watch - compiles sass but only after watch ends

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Not sure if this is a bug or mis configuration on my part, but when using grunt to watch some sass files, it definitely watches the files but only only compiles sass and updates to the destination file when i exit the watcher.

here is my watch node:

```
watch: {
    sass : {
        files: [sassPath.scss],
        tasks: ['sass']
    }
}
```

For example this the what is currently happening:

```
 1. I do `grunt watch` on the command line
2. Start editing sass files
3. Command line notifies me that the change has been detected and it runs the sass task successfully
4. I manually look at the destination css file - no changes
5. ctrl + c to close the watcher while looking in the destination css file - i can see it updated as soon as the watch closes
```

I would really like the destination css file to update as soon as sass is compiled

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `grunt watch:sass` task. Have you tried running it by itself? That's not an usual behavior for a `watch` task, though I would have to have a closer look at your `Gruntfile.js` to see if something else there is causing problems. Try updating your local `grunt` and the relevant dependencies (`watch` and `sass`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there seems to be a bug in a certain update that prevents your gruntfile.js from working, I had the same issue and one day after an update via composer the file just stopped working, I had to change the watch part to look something like this and fixed it:

```
        // Watch for files and folder changes
    watch: {
        sass: {
            files: ['<%= options.sass.base %>/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['sass']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: 35729,
            },
            files: [
                'app/views/*/*.php',
                '{tmp/<%= options.css.base %>,<%= options.css.base %>}/{,*/}*.css',
                '{tmp/<%= options.js.base %>,<%= options.js.base %>}/{,*/}*.js',
                '{tmp/<%= options.sass.base %>,<%= options.sass.base %>}/{,*/}*.css',
            ]
        },
        options: {
            livereload: true
        },
        files: '<%= options.watch.files %>',
        tasks: ['default', 'notify:watch']
    }
```

Comment: Nothing is necessarily wrong with his configuration - as far as his description and code are concerned. But it's impossible to know if everything is ok without looking at his `Gruntfile.js`. Someone might of course appreciate your approach with the `watch` task but I don't think this answer is adding much value to the problem he's describing (as it is at the time of this writing)... Because you're basically doing the same he did, with bells and whistles. :) Peace.

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée yes this bells and whistles is a temporary fix for a bug that I have already reported on github. I should have mentioned that!